# Qt 4.7 using Eclipse on windows?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt4, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Has anyone had luck getting Qt Eclipse integration working on windows?

Here is what I did, to no avail:

1. Download latest Qt SDK, and install.
2. Download the Eclipse for C/C++ developers bundle, and install.
3. Download latest Qt/eclipse integration.  (Not so new... http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/ )

At this point I can create a "qt project" in Eclipse, but the build buttons are greyed out.  (Started Eclipse both normally and via the Qt/Mingw shortcut)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out that Qt is no longer really putting any effort to support Eclipse.  They want to push Qt Creator.

The plugin has not been updated for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your QT version to Eclipse?

Windows->Preferences->Qt

Comment: Hmm.  I don't see any option there.